# error: no matching function for call to 'Auto::Auto()'

Tags: c++, class

I have created 3 classes: `Auto` (means "car"), `Klant` (means "customer") and `AutoVerhuur` (means "car dealership).

In my `main()`, I have created `Auto` and `Klant` objects, and am trying to create an `AutoVerhuur` object.

In this last class, I basically want to reference to a specifc `Klant` and `Auto` (which customer rented which car).  But, when I try that, I get an error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'Auto::Auto()'

How do I correctly reference other objects in my object?

Here is my code, if you want to take a look:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

```
class Auto{
    private:
    string type;
    double prijs_per_dag;

    public:
    Auto(string type, double prijs_per_dag){
        this->type = type;
        this->prijs_per_dag = prijs_per_dag;
    }

    void set_prijs_per_dag(double percentage){
        this->prijs_per_dag = percentage;
    }

    double get_prijs_per_dag(){
        return prijs_per_dag;
    }
};
```

```
class Klant{
    private:
    string naam;
    double korting_percentage;

    public:
    Klant(string naam):
        naam(naam){}
    

    void set_korting(double percentage){
        this->korting_percentage = percentage;
    }

    double get_korting(){
        return this->korting_percentage;
    }

    string get_name(){
        return naam;
    }

    void set_name(string naam){
        this->naam = naam;
    }
};
```

```
class AutoHuur{
    private:
    int aantal_dagen;
    Auto wagen;
    Klant huur;

    public:
    AutoHuur(Auto car, Klant huurder, int dagen){
        wagen = car;
        huur = huurder;
        aantal_dagen = dagen;
    }
};
```

```
int main(){
    Klant k("Mijnheer de Vries");
    k.set_korting(10.0);

    Auto a1("Peugeot 207", 50);
    
    AutoHuur ah1(a1, k, 4);    
}
```

Comment: Use an initializer list. It's a basic C++ feature, but wherever it is that newbies learn C++, it  seems it doesn't bother to mention it.

Comment: FYI, if you name your class members differently than the parameters, you won't need to use the `this->` syntax.  Some coding guidelines suggest prefixing members with "m_" while other coding guidelines suggest append "_" to the member names.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Auto` class does not have a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) defined, but your `AutoHuur` class has an `Auto wagen;` data member which the compiler is trying to default-construct (because you haven't told it otherwise), hence the error.

So, you need to either:

- give the `Auto` class a default constructor, eg:

  ```
  Auto(){
      this->type = "";
      this->prijs_per_dag = 0;
      // or whatever default values make sense for your needs...
  }
  ```
- Otherwise, change the constructor of the `AutoHuur` class to use its [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to construct the `wagen` member using the desired `Auto` constructor (you should do the same for the other data members, too), eg:

  ```
  AutoHuur(Auto car, Klant huurder, int dagen)
      : wagen(car), huur(huurder), aantal_dagen(dagen)
  {
  }
  ```

Comment: A right boss you are, this solved my problem. Thanks for helping ;p.